# how to display limited records in a jsp page

Tags: jsp, pagination

i need to display limited no of records in a my page. i have around 10,000 records and when I run my java web application,on submitting the form it says "Error query" 10,650 matches found, can fetch  less than 995 rows only".

hence how do I use pagination and print say 500 records each page?

Any ideas is really helpful.

```
 <table name="Table1" style="width:300px" border="1" cellpadding="5">
<thead>
 <th>FullName</th>
<th>Givename</th>
<th>LastName</th>
  <th>Manager</th>
    <th>Email</th>
   <th>PhoneNumber</th>
       <th>Title</th>
     <th>Description</th>
         </thead>

        <tbody>
<%

  for(User temp1:users)
  {

  out.print("<tr>");

  out.print("<td>");

   out.print(temp1.getFullName());

      out.print("</td>");
  out.print("<td>");

  out.print(temp1.getGivenName());

  out.print("</td>"); 
  out.print("<td>");

 out.print(temp1.getSn());

 out.print("</td>"); 
 out.print("<td>");

 out.print(temp1.getManager());

  out.print("</td>"); 
  out.print("<td>");

 out.print(temp1.getEmail());

  out.print("</td>"); 
 out.print("<td>");

out.print(temp1.getTelephoneNumber());

 out.print("</td>"); 
 out.print("<td>");

 out.print(temp1.getTitle());

 out.print("</td>"); 
 out.print("<td>");

out.print(temp1.getDescription());

out.print("</td>"); 


  out.print("</tr>");

    }
   %></tbody>
   </table>
```

It will print row by row.the output is more than 10,000 records hence I need to fetch it 500 records per page. Now did you get my question?Thanks

Comment: Hi,I am not pulling from a database. i am displaying a record from a servlet.hence created a table in jsp and displayed the result in a table format. I don't have any unique id or even row nums for my table

Comment: not hardcoded, created a table in jsp page and displayed the result in each cell.I have a for loop that prints emp name,designation,manager etc etc row by row for 10,000 users. if I have to display only 500 records per page how do i do it

Comment: Yes the users result is coming from a servlet and it is fetching from a database.All i need to do is change the output.jsp (where it is pulling 10,000 records) just format it in a way that it pulls only few records at a time. do i need to use a for loop and pagination

Comment: The limiting should be in the servlet. No point in loading 10000000 records, saving them in a request attribute, forwarding to the JSP, then only displaying 500 in the JSP. That would be a massive waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some library to display a table and external pagination.
For example `displayTag`: http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/tut_externalSortAndPage.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you.. I was able to solve this at the server level and didn't make any changes at the client level(I mean the jsp). The query which I gave to pull the records from the database  was "select * from device" hence it couldn't fetch that many records.
Just made a change in the query by selecting 2 columns from the table and could see the output of 10,000 records in my jsp. :)
I am working on exporting that to CSV file.

Thanks again.